# OpenNLP Tokenizer - Incompatible Types Error?

Tags: opennlp, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to create a Tokenizer using the Apache OpenNLP API. I have extracted the code from their site but I get an 'incompatible types' error for the following line of code in the Tokenize class:

Tokenize tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);

Does anyone know the reason for this error as it appears that they shouldn't be incompatible?

This is the main class:

```
public class OpenNLP {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {            
        try
        {
        Tokenizer T = new Tokenizer();        
        T.Tokenize();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

This is the Tokenize class with the error:

```
public class Tokenize {

    public void Tokenize() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException 
    {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");

    TokenizerModel model = new TokenizerModel(is);

    Tokenize tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);

    String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize("Hi. How are you? This is Mike.");

    for (String a : tokens)
        System.out.println(a);

    is.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this now. The following line:

```
Tokenize tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);
```

Should have been:

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);
```